# Disabling enemy AI

Tags: pc, halo-combat-evolved

I'm looking to take some pictures of the Grunts in Halo: Combat Evolved for a possible project. Of course, this isn't easy when they keep running from or shooting at you.
Is there a program that will allow you to disable the enemy AI so that they don't do anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I suggest using the console command `game_speed #`**, where # is an integer between `0` and `20`. `0` will cause the game to pause.

In order to be able to use console commands, you need to enter Developer Mode.
To do so, create a shortcut of the Halo executable, and in the target field of the shortcut add

```
-console -devmode
```

You might have to put the rest of the target between quotations marks, e.g.

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Games\Halo Custom Edition\haloce.exe" -console -devmode
```

More information can be found [here](https://halo.fandom.com/wiki/Developer_Mode).

Once the game is started in Dev Mode, the console can be accessed using the <kbd>`</kbd> or <kbd>~</kbd> key on QWERTY keyboards (<kbd>²</kbd> on AZERTY, I believe).

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I've downloaded Halo: Custom Edition but I'm struggling to get it to work (it won't launch), even after patching it.

Comment: Post it as another question?

Comment: The issue was I installed the "halopc" patch, not "haloce". It's now working and I have downloaded some campaign maps to use with it. I also think that the cheat_bump_possession command will be useful (although a little buggy) as I can get close to the Covenant without them attacking.